# Do you have to admit that you lied retroactively?

Tags: halacha, mistakes, sheker-false

If someone asks you a personal question and you provide an answer. Upon further inspection you realize that you gave the wrong answer. Do you now have a halachic obligation to find the person and tell him you made a mistake or you can simple "live and let live"?

Comment: you mean it could be g'neivat daas if you don't?

Comment: @CashCow, either that or *tirchak min hasheker* - which is probably the same thing.